# Input debounce with angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In an application I need to send an event on input debounce.

I'm trying this :

```
   @ViewChild('messageInput') messageInput: ElementRef;
   private inputTimeOutObservable: any;

    setTypingTimeOut(){
          this.inputTimeOutObservable = Observable.fromEvent(this.messageInput.nativeElement, 'input')
            .map((event: Event) => (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value)
            .debounceTime(1000)
            .distinctUntilChanged()
            .subscribe(data => {
              this.sendEvent();
            });
    }
    ngOnDestroy() {
        if (this.inputTimeOutObservable) {
          this.inputTimeOutObservable.unsubscribe();
          this.inputTimeOutObservable = null;
        }
      }
```

The input do other stuff but here it is :

```
 <input #messageInput id="message" type="text" (ngModelChange)="inputTextChanges($event)"
               [(ngModel)]="messageValue" (keyup)='keyUp.next($event)'>
```

The event is not fired and I don't see why here. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on you code, here's a working example:

*component.html*

```
<input #messageInput id="message" type="text" [(ngModel)]="messageValue">
```

*component.ts*

```
import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Rx";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input-debounce',
  templateUrl: './input-debounce.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-debounce.component.css']
})
export class InputDebounceComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('messageInput') messageInput: ElementRef;
  public messageValue: string = "";
  private inputTimeOutObservable: any;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.setTypingTimeOut();
  }

  setTypingTimeOut() {

    this.inputTimeOutObservable = Observable.fromEvent(this.messageInput.nativeElement, 'input')
      .map((event: Event) => (<HTMLInputElement>event.target).value)
      .debounceTime(1000)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(this.messageValue);
        console.timeEnd("Input changed after."); // No matter how frequent you type, this will always be > 1000ms
        console.time("Input changed after."); // start track input change fire time
      });
  }

}
```

Comment: Where did you call `setTypingTimeOut`?

Comment: in the constructor of the component

Comment: Then that was the problem. Call any code that queries dom elements inside `ngAfterViewInit()` (`ViewChild` will be available in `ngAfterViewInit`). Another thing, import `Obeservable` from `rxjs/Rx` (not from `rxjs/Observable`).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a reactive form control you could do the following:

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

public myCtrl: FormControl = new FormControl();
myCtrl.valueChanges.debounceTime(1000).subscribe(value => ...);
```

And your template gets cleaner:

```
<input #messageInput id="message" type="text" [formControl]="myCtrl">
```

Comment: Hm when I add FormControl to my module I get `Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'FormControl' imported by the module 'ChatModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.`

Comment: Did you import ReactiveFormsModule in your module?

Comment: Ok, that kind of works but the event is fired at the initialization of the component

Comment: Either check if data is available or do a cold observable using .map() instead of .subscribe()

Comment: Could you provide an example with map() I don't see how that could replace a subscribe

Comment: For your use case it is not the thing you need bc you are not returning values based on that changes. Anyway you can make sure that the subscribe function doesn't call the sendEvent method, when initializing has not finished and the component is just being created.